# PHP - Convert encode array to a normal array

Tags: php, arrays, rest

I'm having an issue with an array, in my rest app I'm trying to get user data but what I'm getting is someting like this:

```
    array(1) {
  ["------WebKitFormBoundaryluJdsCUm4081zfQj
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
  string(1655) ""vacante"

Otros
------WebKitFormBoundaryluJdsCUm4081zfQj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="estado"

cdmx
------WebKitFormBoundaryluJdsCUm4081zfQj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="municipio"

benito
------WebKitFormBoundaryluJdsCUm4081zfQj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="requerimientos"

ffffdfdfdddffdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfernando
------WebKitFormBoundaryluJdsCUm4081zfQj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="categoria"

["Ventas"]
}
```

It looks like if is encoded but I'm not sure, my question here how do I convert this array into this?:

```
array(15) {
  ["vacante"]=>
  string(5) "Otros"
  ["estado"]=>
  string(4) "cdmx"
  ["municipio"]=>
  string(6) "benito"
  ["requerimientos"]=>
  string(37) "ffffdfdfdddffdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfernando"
  ["categoria"]=>
  string(23) "["Ventas"]
}
```

Comment: What HTTP request verb are you using?

Comment: put, I'm trying to create (insert) data via rest